Assigning Z value along line on raster using QGIS
In QGIS I have a mnt, a line with a Z attribute of value 100.
How can I replace the Z values ​​of the raster that intersect the line (see a buffer around the line) with that of the line, i.e. 100?
I want to do the opposite of draping (the idea being to "build a wall on the raster").



Optionally create a small buffer around your line
Rasterize your vector layer (Processing Toolbox/GDAL/Vector conversion/Rasterize with attribute or fixed value). It'll burn the the value into the raster.

